# VScode hangs on startup

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I start vscode I get this error.
In the terminal pane, it looks like there is a loop writing hundreds of powershell prompts.
And then after a while, I get this:
[image]

I have Rebooted, uninstalled, cleaned my pc, installed vscode again.
I have tried to find solution here, but none apply.
I also have tried to start without extention and deleted my settings json file to get a new.

But the error is still there.

Comment: Seems a bit odd.  Out of interest, have you tried loading a Powershell window separately outside of VS Code and do you get the same looping output?

Comment: yes, it is odd...  I tried to start pwsh.exe and powershell.exe now, and both start up just fine.   Any other tips on what I can try, or logs to check?

Comment: SOLVED.  Uninstalled pwsh.exe 7.3.3 and oh-my-posh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue removing installation of power shell 6.1.
I think actual VSCode **version 1.82.2** does support power shell different from the default Windows power shell.
The complete version information from the help of VSCode is :

```
Version: 1.82.2
Commit: abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d
Date: 2023-09-14T05:55:25.390Z
Electron: 25.8.1
ElectronBuildId: 23779380
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

Comment: Yes.  Reinstalling Powershell Core (and Oh-My-Posh) was the resolution for me too.